# Can't generate migration in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've started to learn phoenix framework and having some troubles when trying to create my migration, here is my schema :

```
defmodule Lclp.User do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Lclp.User


  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :username, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

When i run the migration generator this output me something like this :

```
defmodule Lclp.Repo.Migrations.UserAdd do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

  end
end
```

The change function is empty when it should be something like :

```
    def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      add :username, :string
      add :email, :string
      add :password, :string
      add :password_hash, :string

      timestamps()
    end
   end
```

My User schema is in the main folder with repo.ex as you can see here :
[image]

Does anyone have an idea why the generator generate an empty migration ?

Comment: What command are you using to generate the migration? Also, since your `:password` field is virtual, you should not include it in the migration.

Comment: i'm using `mix ecto.gen.migration create_user`. I'll delete `:password`, thanks.

Comment: I think you will want to look at [`phx.gen.schema`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Schema.html) instead. `ecto.gen.migration` does not try to create a migration based on your code. It only creates the migration file.

Comment: That make sense, i'll try that.

Comment: @JustinWood I think you should put this advise as an answer. Many future visitors might mess generators up.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to look at [`phx.gen.schema`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Schema.html) instead. `ecto.gen.migration` does not look at your code to attempt to build an actual migration for you. It just generates the scaffold file.